# Thread Safe XML Validation in Java 5

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, xml-validation, java-5

So I was looking around for a thread safe Java XML Validator and none seem to exist:

[`SchemFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) - documented as not thread-safe

[`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html) -documented as not thread-safe

[`Schema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) - documented as thread safe, [but actually isn't](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXP-55)

What is there beyond the `javax` implementation? Note that I am under `Java 5` and cannot use any `Guava` libraries or really anything beyond `apache-commons`, which I have already explored and discovered [the Validator framework](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/), but I am unsure whether this is actually thread-safe as it says the following:

> Currently Validator instances may be safely reused if the current ValidatorResources are the same, as long as you have completed any previous validation, and you do not try to utilize a particular Validator instance from more than one thread at a time.

I assume this means that as long as each of my threads has one instance then we are in business.

But do I have any other options, something obvious I have missed?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use multiple validators? I think that's the most obvious option. They can't be that expensive to create.

Comment: We don't currently have access to the `apache-commons` and it will take approval / red tape for me to get it in to our dependencies, so I was hoping for another, easier native option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple instances of the built-in ones. Non-thread-safe just means you can't share the instance between multiple threads at the same time (`SimpleDateFormat` and `Random` are good examples).

You can also use `ThreadLocal` to give each thread their own instance (instead of potentially creating your own "solution").

Comment: Ah is it really that simple? Guess my question should have been `what makes a class thread-safe`!

Comment: @Rossiar Indeed. Threading is complex, so it's easy to make mistakes or not now exactly how some concurrent things work. A well written question usually gives the correct answer, even if it might not be the answer to what's in the title.

Answer (score 1):

It's important for the Schema to be thread-safe, so you can compile a schema once and use it repeatedly in multiple threads. You're suggesting that the Xerces schema claims to be thread-safe and isn't: that would be a problem.

It's not important for the Validator to be thread-safe, because you should be creating a new Validator each time you validate an instance document.

The other thing to bear in mind is that JAXP is closely tied in with DOM, and DOM is not thread-safe. That can be a big problem.

As for your question, is there an alternative, the answer is yes: Saxon-EE provides an alternative XSD validation engine, with full thread-safety on both compiled schemas and instance documents.